# Create blue "tutorial" dialogs as in Android 4.4

Tags: android, android-view, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I would like to create some "dialogs" like those shown in Android 4.4 for example when you are first shown immersive mode.  The little arrow is important for me because I would like to have the dialogin different places on the screen.

This is what I'm talking about: [image]

Do I need to create a custom `AlertDialog`? How do I move it around, can I use the coordinates of a View? I don't really know where to start. Are there any examples on creating this type of thing? I am not interested in using the `ShowcaseView` library as in my opinion has the "old" holo look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the coordinate of views using `getLocationOnScreen()`, make sure to call this after the views have been inflated (so, not in onCreate() of your activity) or else you will be returned default int values (i.e. 0).

You should probably create your own [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).  Incorporate your own custom layout which contains the little bubble and the button.  A Quick and dirty sample for the onCreateDialog() would have the following

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
// Get rid of the annoying alert dialog title bar
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
// You must set the content view after requesting window features, not before.
dialog.setContentView(someView);
// Make the dialog full screen
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
//Dim the background
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.argb(80, 0, 0, 0));
```

To incorporate the little arrow, you can try having variations of 9-patch images as the background of the little bubble.  Another alternative would be to have an arrowhead and a bubble put into the same container, and setting the margin/padding between them to 0.  Since you have the coordinates you can adjust the horizontal margins of the arrowhead accordingly.  This is actually a pretty cool idea, I think I'll try my own interpretation of it this weekend.

I have actually been working on my own interpretation of the showcase library, [Here is what i achieved](http://imgur.com/a/dhshO).  Much of the dynamic position changing should be the same I would think

Comment: Does this mean I need to create a new `DialogFragment` every time I need to move the "box". Or does this act exactly like a normal `Fragment`?

Comment: You can structure it that way if you want.  A `DialogFragment` is really just a dialog inside a `Fragment` class

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, which apps already have this tutorial style embedded? It would be cool have a real sample to work off of.

Comment: I haven't actually found any apps with a full tutorial in this style. I want to achieve the same effect as the ShowcaseView library but in the newer style. This is an app which use ShowcaseView: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.franco.kernel

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure the nexus 5's GEL launcher has the new kit kat style tutorial included, but I can't get it to reproduce without a factory reset, clearing its data didn't really work.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the Google Search app data as that is where the majority of the code is for the launcher not the GEL apk.

Comment: That did it! thanks for the suggestion.  Nice to have an actual sample to work with